# Updating checkboxes in CRUDE app with Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I'm very new to node.js, EJS. and mongoDB. I am making a crud app with basic functions and all seems to work fine, except the checkboxes. So I have 7 checkboxes, one for each day of the week and I ask the user to select the days they like.

I am able to add these to the database and further read them from the "Update_User" Page. But, when I try to update the checkboxes, it basically overwrites the array of selected values with ONE day. So for example: if I choose Sunday, Monday, and Tuesday the array is => ["Sunday" , "Monday" , "Tuesday"] and after updating it to include Wednesday, the array just becomes ["Wednesday"]

Here are the codes:

```
<div class="days" id="days">
                            <label>Repeat every:</label>                
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">                                    
                                <input id="sunday" type="checkbox" value="Sunday" name="days"  <%= user.days.includes("Sunday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="sunday">Sunday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="monday" type="checkbox" value="Monday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Monday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="monday">Monday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="tuesday" type="checkbox" value="Tuesday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Tuesday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="tuesday">Tuesday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="wednesday" type="checkbox" value="Wednesday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Wednesday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="wednesday">Wednesday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="thursday" type="checkbox" value="Thursday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Thursday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="thursday">Thursday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="friday" type="checkbox" value="Friday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Friday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="friday">Friday</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="checkbox_freq">
                                <input id="saturday" type="checkbox" value="Saturday" name="days" <%= user.days.includes("Saturday") ? 'checked' : '' %>>
                                <span class="check"></span>
                                <label for="saturday">Saturday</label>
                            </div> 
                        </div>
```

The above is the form through which the user selects the options. I have other fields such as Text Inputs and Radio inputs, they seem to work perfectly.

Below is the code in my "index.js" -> This executes when I press the submit button:

```
$("#update_user").submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
alert("YALLOOOO");
var unindexed_array = $(this).serializeArray();
var data = {}

$.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
    data[n['name']] = n['value']
})


var request = {
    "url" : `http://localhost:3000/api/users/${data.id}`,
    "method" : "PUT",
    "data" : data
}

$.ajax(request).done(function(response){
    alert("Data Updated Successfully!");
})
```

})

And below is the code from my "controller.js" which I believe manages the CRUD operations:

```
exports.update = (req, res)=>{
if(!req.body){
    return res
        .status(400)
        .send({ message : "Data to update can not be empty"})
}

const id = req.params.id;
Userdb.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body, { useFindAndModify: false})
    .then(data => {
        if(!data){
            res.status(404).send({ message : `Cannot Update user with ${id}. Maybe user not found!`})
        }else{                
            res.send(data)               
        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(500).send({ message : "Error Update user information"})
    })
```

}

I tried implementing a function just to check if my checkboxes are working:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetSelected() {
    //Create an Array.
    var days = new Array();

    //Reference the Table.
    var selected_days = document.getElementById("days");

    //Reference all the CheckBoxes in Table.
    var chks = selected_days.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

    // Loop and push the checked CheckBox value in Array.
    for (var i = 0; i < chks.length; i++) {
        if (chks[i].checked) {
            days.push(chks[i].value);
        }
    }

    //Display the selected CheckBox values.
    if (selected.length > 0) {
        alert("Selected values: " + days.join(","));
    }
};
```

This always gives me the correct array as the alert. If I can some how update the the array "days" in the mongoDB, it might work but I have no clue how to do it. This is the first time I'm using mongoDB.

Please let me know if any further code snippets are required.

Comment: Where does the array not contain all the values? In the controller or on the response from the controller ?

Comment: When I send a GET request to localhost from postman, it shows the incomplete array. I'm not sure about "In the controller or on the response from the controller ?". Is there any way I could check this for you?

Comment: You can console.log it on the controller.js when you get the data and just before you send the response

Comment: Neither of them shows the correct array. The one where I get the data AND after I send the response show the array with only one element. My guess is that it's not pushing the elements into the array

Comment: What is the value of unindexed_array? Also, is #update_user the id of the form?

Comment: unindexed_array is 5: 
5:{name: "days", value: "Sunday"}
6: {name: "days", value: "Monday"}
7: {name: "days", value: "Tuesday"}

AND YES, UPDATE_USER IS THE ID OF THE FORM